# How to add plug-in to Sublime Text from git source?

Tags: git, sublimetext2

I am new to git and I am seeing a similar question but it is for windows! I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and I have sublime text editor installed. I was looking at a plug-in from git called sublime_text_alternative_autocompletion. What do I have to do in order to get this plug in on my installation of sublime or any git add-in for that matter? The read me file really does not have much information.

Comment: The easiest solution would be package control, as explained in the [README](https://github.com/atombender/sublime_text_alternative_autocompletion#installation-using-package-control-simplest). Why don’t you use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step1: Install Package Control via https://sublime.wbond.net/installation. The instructions to install the same is available in the link

Step2: Press CMD+SHIFT+P. This will open up a dialog. Type Package Control:Install Package

[image]

Step3: Wait for sometime:-)

Step4: Search for "alternative autocompletion" and hit ENTER.

[image]

Step5: Blow up some balloons and party!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your [ReadMe](https://github.com/atombender/sublime_text_alternative_autocompletion) contains enough info:

Go to a folder named `Packages` in your `Sublime` source code

```
cd  /path/to/Package/folder
```

then git clone to download the source:

```
git clone git://github.com/alexstaubo/sublime_text_alternative_autocompletion.git
```